# Rails 6: How to use generate_series to show if an action was taken on a given day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm building a simple Habit Tracker. A User has many Habits and I need to track if they've completed a Habit on a given day across time.

user.rb

```
  has_many :habits
  has_many :completed_habits
```

habit.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :completed_habits
```

completed_habit.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :habit
```

I have a method on my Habit model that I would like to create an array of dates with either a 1 or 0 value, and then I'll just loop through that array in the view and show an X or a Check.

```
  def sequence

    query = <<-SQL
      SELECT
        series_date,
        COUNT(habit_id) AS completed
      FROM generate_series(
             ( SELECT created_at::date FROM habits
               WHERE habits.id = :user_id
             ),
             CURRENT_DATE,
             '1 day'
           ) AS series_date
      LEFT JOIN completed_habits ON completed_habits.created_at::date = series_date
      WHERE habit_id = :habit_id
      AND user_id = :user_id
      GROUP BY series_date
      ORDER BY series_date DESC;
    SQL

    Habit.find_by_sql([query, { user_id: self.user, habit_id: self.id } ])

  end
```

When I run that query in Postico, I get the following, which is almost there (I'd rather there be a row for the dates that don't have a completed_habit on that day with a completed value of 0):

[image]

However, when I render @habit.sequence in my Rails view, I get this:

[image]

I don't understand why it isn't returning the series_date, habit_id, and completed values I'm seeing in Postico.

UPDATE:

Using Model.connection.exec_query I've now got this working, but it still feels pretty clunky to me. Is there a cleaner, more "Railsy" way to get this done?

```
  def sequence

    query = <<-SQL
      SELECT
        series_date,
        COUNT(habit_id) AS completed
      FROM generate_series(
             ( SELECT created_at::date FROM habits
               WHERE habits.id = $1
             ),
             CURRENT_DATE,
             '1 day'
           ) AS series_date
      LEFT JOIN completed_habits ON completed_habits.created_at::date = series_date
      GROUP BY series_date
      ORDER BY series_date ASC;
    SQL

    binds = [
      ActiveRecord::Relation::QueryAttribute.new("habit_id", self.id, ActiveRecord::Type::Integer.new)
    ]

    Habit.connection.exec_query(query, 'sql', binds).to_a

  end
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "completed_habits", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "habit_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "habits", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "frequency"
    t.boolean "is_active"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.text "description"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

Comment: Could you provide your view and the database schema for the model (Habit)?

Comment: @MasafumiOkura Sure, just added the schema!

Comment: Using Arel is an option, but it might simplify the code much. It's possible to make your SQL into ERB and put it into its own file named like `app/sqls/habit_sequence.sql.erb`.